# Window does not display properly

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I have a little problem that I can't solve concerning windows constructed with gtk:

In my program, I have two functions that display a separate gtk.window with content in it (one with a button -displaying a text-, the other with a key press event -displaying a matplotlib figure-). On the first run of the program, the two windows display properly with the contents I asked for, but when I close the separate window and try to display it again I obtain an empty window (in both cases) and I can't figure out why!

If you have some suggestions, I will be glad to read them (I'll work on a little version of my program to test it and add it to the post later).

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the sample I tested, and I think that the same problem occur, the glade file is nothing much (one window and two buttons), but when I click on one of the buttons, the first time the window is normal and when I close and reopen I have the same problem as in my real program.

```
import gtk
import gtk.glade

class Testwin:
    # Initialisation of window and connection of signals
    def __init__(self):
        self.Main = gtk.Builder()
        self.Main.add_from_file('Testwin.glade')

        self.Mainwindow = self.Main.get_object("Main_window")
        self.Main.connect_signals(self)

        self.extWindow1 = self.Main.get_object("External_window1")
        self.extWindow2 = self.Main.get_object("External_window2")


    def on_window_destroy(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def display_window1(self, widget):
        self.extWindow1.show_all()        

    def display_window2(self, widget):
        self.extWindow2.show_all()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Testwin()
    gtk.main()
```

(I put the .glade file as well in case someone wants to test it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="External_window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="External_window2">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="Main_window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkHButtonBox" id="hbuttonbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="display_window2" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="display_window1" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: There's no way anyone can guess what you're doing wrong until you post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Edited. While working on it, I noticed that it doesn't matter if I put destroy() or hide() for closing the window, I will have the same effect.
What is also funny is that if the window is not a main window but a popup, the problem disappear (but with that the window can't be moved and I need to add a close button).

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that the popup windows (or possibly just their contents) are getting destroyed; you can't show a destroyed window. An easy way to test this is to add a `destroy` signal handler to the popup windows that just logs something and see if it's getting triggered. To fix it, you either have to create and destroy, or show and hide, not show and destroy.

Comment: The problem is that even with hide, when shown again the window display none of the widgets I defined. Still, creating the window manually with python and not glade each time I execute my command is the best workaround I've found so far. Thanks for the precisions abarnert!